Issue storing numbers in server side next js app code
The intended function of this code is to get 3 prices hour day and month and then store them and repeatedly calculate the percentage change from those times until it is time to update them. In my current code the Old Price keeps getting returned to the console as 0 or as the current price repeatedly but I want it to be returned as the same price over and over until the specified time has passed. Can anyone see why the Old Price stays at 0 or currentprice, and why the percentages stay at 0 instead of actual percent change being calculated ?
Here is the link to the api page if that helps at all....
https://docs.dexscreener.com/api/reference
and the request I am using from it is
Get one or multiple pairs by token address (rate-limit 300 requests per minute)
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';


let priceData: { priceUsd: string, marketCap: string } = { priceUsd: '0', marketCap: '' };
let priceHistory = {
  hour: '0.00', // Initialize with numeric strings
  day: '0.00',
  week: '0.00',
};


let pctChange ={
  hour: '0.00', // Initialize with numeric strings
  day: '0.00',
  week: '0.00',

}

let isInitialFetch = true;




const fetchPriceData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.dexscreener.com/latest/dex/tokens/0x532f27101965dd16442E59d40670FaF5eBB142E4');
    const data = await response.json();
    priceData = {
      priceUsd: data.pairs[0].priceUsd || '0', // Ensure it's always a valid number
      marketCap: data.pairs[0].marketCap,
    };

    if (isInitialFetch) {
      // Only set the initial prices after the first successful fetch
      priceHistory.hour = priceData.priceUsd;
      priceHistory.day = priceData.priceUsd;
      priceHistory.week = priceData.priceUsd;
      isInitialFetch = false; // Disable the flag after setting the initial prices
    }

    console.log("Old price:", priceHistory.hour);
    console.log("Current price:", priceData.priceUsd);

    // Calculate the percentage change for each timeframe
    const calculatePercentChange = (oldPrice: string, newPrice: string): string => {
      const old = parseFloat(oldPrice);
      const current = parseFloat(newPrice);

      if (isNaN(old) || isNaN(current) || old === 0) {
        return '0'; // Avoid invalid calculations or division by 0
      }

      const percentChange = ((current - old) / old) * 100;
      return percentChange > 0 ? `+${percentChange.toFixed(2)}` : percentChange.toFixed(2);
    };

    if (parseFloat(priceHistory.hour) > 0 && parseFloat(priceData.priceUsd) > 0) {
      pctChange.hour = calculatePercentChange(priceHistory.hour, priceData.priceUsd);
    }
    if (parseFloat(priceHistory.day) > 0 && parseFloat(priceData.priceUsd) > 0) {
      pctChange.day = calculatePercentChange(priceHistory.day, priceData.priceUsd);
    }
    if (parseFloat(priceHistory.week) > 0 && parseFloat(priceData.priceUsd) > 0) {
      pctChange.week = calculatePercentChange(priceHistory.week, priceData.priceUsd);
    }

    console.log("Price data updated:", priceData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching price data:', error);
  }
};



// Fetch price data every 5 seconds
setInterval(fetchPriceData, 5 * 1000);

// Reset the price history every hour, day, and week
setInterval(() => {
  priceHistory.hour = priceData.priceUsd || '0';
}, 60 * 60 * 1000); // Every hour

setInterval(() => {
  priceHistory.day = priceData.priceUsd || '0';
}, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // Every day

setInterval(() => {
  priceHistory.week = priceData.priceUsd || '0';
}, 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // Every week

// Initial fetch
fetchPriceData();

export async function GET() {
  return NextResponse.json({
    price: priceData.priceUsd,
    marketCap: priceData.marketCap,
    percentChanges: pctChange,
  });
}

I tried initializing the values of priceHistory to numbers instead of strings, but that did't do anything.

You are using a single variable to mean two different things.
In the "initial fetch" stage, you are storing the PRICE in hour, day, and week.  But when you do the update, you are storing the PERCENTAGE CHANGE in hour, day, and week.  Since the prices don't change much in 5 seconds, the percentage change is always going to be 0.
You need to decide whether you need two separate structures, one for "actual price this hour" and one for "percentage change over the hour".

I updated the code in the question....If you look I added the pctChange struct, to hold the percent changes. But when I get to this line of
code console.log("Old price:", priceHistory.hour);
it continually returns 0.0 or -49 for some reason but I don't know why it would do that since it is set like this priceHistory.hour = priceData.priceUsd;
